# How to use acast correctly on R data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, aggregate, reshape2

I have an R data frame in this form with thousands of records:

```
account_id             timestamp    days_since_launch   region  used
    1263562             6/23/16           5               SFO    57
    3821750             6/24/16           11              ATL    10
```

I want to convert it into a form, where the column names are:

```
account_id    timestamp  days_since_launch  SFO ATL SEA NYC SLC
```

Note: In here the columns SFO, ATL, SEA, NYC, SLC are the unique entries of region in the original dataset. I want the entries in these region columns to have the corresponding numeric entry in used.

How can this be done in R?

I tried `as.data.frame(acast(inputDF, account_id + timestamp ~ region, value.var="used"))`

The issue I have with this is: it forms a column name called `account_id_timestamp` with the account id's and timestamps concatenated like 1263562_6/23/16 . It also gives a warning: "Aggregation function missing: defaulting to length"

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, what you've tried and where you feel you fall short.

Comment: `acast` is from reshape2, not dplyr.

Comment: I have included what I tried. I am not restricting the answer to be only through acast. Any other function could be used as part of the accepted answer-as long as it works.

Comment: Does `spread(df, region, used)` work for you?

Comment: It works like a charm